# Converting doubles to integers

Tags: java, integer, rounding

I would like to convert a double (for example price with a value of 7.90) to an integer without losses! I am making a program that processes money, and I have to input them as doubles, and then convert them to integers so that I can proccess them and for example when I have 7.90 euros and i want to convert it to cents it will appear as 789 cents instead of 790! please help me :) thanks in advance

Comment: 1) Please create a complete, minimal and verifiable example, 2) please tag what programming language this is in

Comment: @Magisch I edited it and said which is the main problem

Comment: Could you use english variable names, at least for the example? Even when writing code only for yourself it is recommendable to use english names since you can almost never be sure that no one else will ever have to read it.

Comment: @D.Everhard i wrote what each one means

Comment: Yes, I am just saying it improves readability if one doesn't have to get out of the code to search for meaning of a variable.

Answer (score 0):

```
More specificaly the problem is that if it was a double it would originaly save 59.999999 instead of 60
```

Data type double variables are not capable of storing some values exactly, 60 is one of those values, so you should either a) use a different data type (float suffers from the same problems), or b) account for that using a tolerance in your checks.

In your case your variable shows 59.9999999 simply because its the closest that data type `double` can get to 60.

Comment: @Magish So what should I do in order to save it as 60?

Comment: @KritonGeorgiou Why is it a double type to begin with?

Comment: @Magish Because the excercise asked us to request the money as doubles, like 0,1 0,5 etc...

Comment: @KritonGeorgiou any reason why you can't allow double input and then multiply by 100 and cast to int, then display again as double after processing? You can use round up features to round to the nearest high point.

Comment: @Magish actualy that's what I did! The program reads the number as double and it the end when it has to edit it in order to give the change(the part of the code that you see above) I convert it to an integer! and that's what happens

Comment: Another option used on graphic games is to use an Integer multiplied by 100 instead of a Double if you only need two digits precision. Float operations are CPU consuming and in this case you don't need Floats(the origin of the problem), just print money/100 whenever you need to print it.

Comment: @Izuel Thats exactly what I suggested. Floating point math is almost infinitely more cpu expensive then normal integer math is.

Comment: `double` _can_ represent 60 exactly. It is 0x42700000 in IEEE 754 format. See http://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html for a calculator.

Comment: @ErickG.Hagstrom There is no guarantee OP's system uses IEEE 754 format. Its not specified in the C standard which format PCs must use.

Comment: It's Java. Java specifies IEEE 754-1985. See the JLS 8, section 4.2.3. "The floating-point types are float and double, which are conceptually associated with the single-precision 32-bit and double-precision 64-bit format IEEE 754 values and operations as specified in IEEE Standard for Binary Floating-Point Arithmetic, ANSI/IEEE Standard 754-1985 (IEEE, New York)."

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution:

Do not use floating point numbers at all. Instead of saying `1 Euro = 100 * 0.01 Euro`, calculate with Cents: `1 Euro = 100 Cents`. Calculate with Cents as integers and divide by 100 if you need Euros.

Another possibility:

When calculating big amounts of money, where it won't fit into an integer (maybe not even into a long), you use the `BigInteger` or `BigDecimal` classes. This is the usual and probably better approach when working with money. Precision and number of digits are arbitrary, but processing time and memory usage might be higher.

Comment: that's what i did! I converted them in cents in order to be able to divide numbers correctly! the issue is that it saves 60 for example as 59

Comment: I don't think you understand what I mean. In your question, you are stil talking about "7.90 Euros", and that you input them as doubles. It should not be possible to get rounding errors, because you should not get doubles as result. Apart from that, I described two possible solutions, so "that's what I did" seems quite unprobable to me. Did you try both solutions? Note that the second one is the usual and recommended approach, as I stated in my answer.